# SharpFont nuget added but reference to Assembly not found

Tags: c#

I have been having this issue for some time. I'm using SharpFont in my project and I have tried adding it through Nuget with the following command:
*"Install-Package SharpFont"*
which looks like it works and the reference is added. But the following code fails to compile:

```
using System;
using SharpFont;

namespace TEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

With this error in the console: *"The type or namespace name 'SharpFont' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"* which makes me think it wasn't installed correctly in the project. The project is completely new and empty.

Have in mind other nuget packages were added succesfully to the project without any issues, so I'm guessing this comes from Sharpfont and not my project, but I haven't found anyone having a similar issue.

Edit: I have tried reinstalling all nuget packages with
`Update-Package –reinstall` but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while installing SharpFont. To fix that first install **SharpFont.Dependencies** *nuget* *package* as SharpFont is dependent on it.

After that you can install SharpFont. Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: No luck, I have uninstalled SharpFont, installed the dependencies nuget package, installed back SharpFont and the issue persists.